# Continuous map $\mathbb{S}^n\to \mathbb{S}^m$

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that any continuous map $\mathbb{S}^n\to \mathbb{S}^m$ is not surjective if $n<m$?

Thanks.

Comment: they can be surjective, but are homotopic to nonsurjective maps (eg hatcher section 4.1)

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not true. There are variations of the Peano curve which provide surjective maps $S^1\to S^n$ for all $n\geq1$.

Comment: Aren't these discontinuous?

Comment: Alex, the whole point of Peano curves is that they are continuous :)

Comment: @Alex: No, they are continuous.

Comment: They're curves, see also the The Hahn–Mazurkiewicz theorem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curves

Comment: @Mariano: and how we can proof that such map $\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{S}^m$ is homotopic to a constant map?

Comment: @Aspirin: degree of such maps is zero, then use the Hopf theorem.

Comment: @Aspirin, you should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @Aspirin In summary, one proof is as follows: let us choose triangulations $h:\left|K\right|\to S^n$ and $k:\left|L\right|\to S^m$ where $K$ and $L$ are simplicial complexes and $n<m$. If $h:\left|K\right|\to \left|L\right|$ is a continuous function, then we know by the finite simplicial approximation theorem that there is a subdivision $K'$ of $K$ and a simplicial map $f:K'\to L$ such that $h$ is homotopic to $f$. However, the image of $f$ is contained in the $n$-skeleton of $L$ (which is a proper subspace of $\left|L\right|$ since the dimension of $L$ is $m>n$). The proof is complete.

Comment: @Aspirin You might wish to look at the following Wikipedia articles: [Simplicial complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex), [Barycentric subdivision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_subdivision), and [Simplicial approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_approximation_theorem). In fact, the subdivision $K'$ of $K$ in my proof above can be chosed to be the $N$th barycentric subdivision of $K$ for some nonnegative integer $N$.

Comment: @Aspirin A version of the simplicial approximation theorem remains true in the case where $K$ and $L$ are arbitrary (not necessarily finite) simplicial complexes. However, in the general case, one needs to consider subdivisions of $K$ more general than barycentric subdivision. The details underyling the ideas that I have presented here can be found in pages 79-99 of *Elements of Algebraic Topology* by James Munkres.