# Let $X$ and $Y$ be homotopy equivalent to $S^2$ and $S^3$ resp. Prove that every continuous map $X\to Y$ is homotopic to a constant map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Revising for an exam - past paper question.
I'm first asked to explain why a triangulation os $S^2$ must contain at least 4 vertices. I believe this might have to do with the fact that 3 vertices would give a triangle, and so fundamental group of this is that of the circle, i.e. additive group of integers. Can't explicitly reason as to why it can't be 2 or 1 currently though...

Then the question above is given - I can assume that $S^n$ can be triangulated and that $S^n$ minus a point is homeomorphic to $R^n$ - but not that X and Y can be triangulated.

So I triangulate $S^2$ and $S^3$ to get K and L resp., and also then using the homotopy equivalences  from X, Y to $S^2$ and $S^3$ I can form a map |K|$\to$$S^2$$\to$X$\to$Y$\to$$S^3$$\to$|L|. By the simple approximation theorem, I can find a subdivision |K'| and a simplicial map $g$: K'$\to$L such that |$g$| is homotopic to this map.

I' not entirely clear where to go from here though. I have a feeling I'll have to remove a point and use the fact that $S^n$ minus a point is homeomorphic to $R^n$ but I'm unclear on how this actually works/whether its correct.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, it is equivalent to show that a map $f:S^2\rightarrow S^3$ is homotopically equivalent to a constant. (Take the map $S^2\to X\to Y\to S^3$) This map is not surjective, up to homotopy see the second answer in the reference, so it takes its values in $S^3-$ point, and the hint tell you that this space is homeomorphic to a point.

For the first question consider the Euler characteristic, if you have less than 3 vertices, the number of edges is inferior to the number of vertices and the Euler number is positive. Contradiction.

[Continuous map between spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98996/continuous-map-between-spheres)

Comment: For the first hint, this may be stupid question - but how do you show that f must not be surjective? For example (one dimension lower), I can take Peano curve and induce a surjective map from $\mathbb{S}^1$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$.

Comment: I would rather use the fact that $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^2)=0$ (proved in Hatcher's book, Prop. 1.14), then by Freudenthal's theorem we have $[\mathbb{S}^2,\mathbb{S}^3]=\pi_2(\mathbb{S}^3)\cong \pi_1(\mathbb{S}^2)=0$, which means exactly what we need.

Comment: See the second answer here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98996/continuous-map-between-spheres

Comment: Well, here is an opposite answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94131/continuous-map-mathbbsn-to-mathbbsm ;) Unless smoothness of $f$ is a consequence of some other assumption here.

Comment: If you read carefully that answer you will see that $f$ is not surjective up to homotopy.

Comment: Yes, and I suppose that whole business with this proof is hidden in this statement.